# Vandalism: moderator attention required

Tags: support, vandalism

Two of my answers were vandalized by @canonizingironize user, here are the links: [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/14330/revisions) and [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/14261/revisions). Both times a very important remark from me has been removed - I'm placing an explicit statement that "if you need more information and/or details - just say it" and it is gone now, no other single edition is done. From the very beginning of the Internet, FIDO and Usenet network discussions were an important part of communication, and - you can call me classy - a RFC conception in them is a key to make the world better:

- **R**equest **F**or **C**omments, if you need a response from people, need to hear the real opinions
- **R**equest **F**or **C**larification, if you need a deeper and/or broader explaination, maybe even in "101-thing" style: there's no dumb questions in this world, I'm saying this as a lector and a teacher.
- **R**equest **F**or **C**ommitment, if you have something that is in need volunteers for testing it
- **R**equest **F**or **C**ouncil, if you need someone with practical experience to help you to find out the nature of things

And this is normal and good-willed manner of having a dialog, both in online and offline worlds. I do understand, that it seems that this particular person has some personal matters towards me not by just mentioning them, but also by behaviour. But I think that question askers should not suffer from this for sure. I can't revert these vandalising edits myself by now, so I'm asking moderators to do so. Also I'm rising a concern about this person's behaviour - it looks inappropriate to the civilized professional community.

Answer (score 3):

personally I would not see this as vandalism , the reason is that  the comment that they can get in touch if they need help is not really needed, the reason is that if they do, then they will either be in touch - or use the comment field. So it does not add much to the post having that comment at the end there. I can understand that you feel that way, but I'm sure it not something personal.

If I where to look through the moderation queue and see this then I would most likely edit it the same way as what he did.